# Cannot see body of function in Dbeaver/PgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I connected to postgreSQL database (version 8.3) with DBeaver. When find function and try to see the body of it I got error message that there is `ERROR WHILE READING SOURCE: SQL Error [42883]: function pg_get_functiondef(oid) does not exists`.
How can I overcome this?

Comment: This function does not exist in 8.3 (!). If for some reason you can't update your database, which I assume is the case, I suggest you use pgAdmin III, which is a kickass IDE for PostgreSQL. Another option would be to use a more generic driver for creating the connection in DBeaver.

Comment: There is exactly the same problem with pgAdmin3 - it doesn't show functions from postgreSQL 8.3

Comment: ah ok, in this case it is much more serious than I thought :D I wonder what would happen if you crate it by hand: `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_get_functiondef(oid)
  RETURNS text AS
'pg_get_functiondef'
  LANGUAGE internal STABLE STRICT
  COST 1;
ALTER FUNCTION pg_get_functiondef(oid)
  OWNER TO postgres;
COMMENT ON FUNCTION pg_get_functiondef(oid) IS 'definition of a function';
`

Comment: Yes, I also wonder but cannot run it. I think if I run the orginal pg_get_functiondef(oid) it would work but so afraid of doing it.

Comment: if it does not exist, you can always drop it afterwards. But it is indeed a quite unorthodox solution :-)

Comment: As @Kayle said this function is written in C language, PostgreSQL just call it. I think the one and only solution is to upgrade version of database or reading function by psql \ef

Comment: True. So I guess you'll end up having to upgrade your database version, which wouldn't be a bad idea :-) good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pg_get_functiondef(oid) was released in Postgres 8.4 ([release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/release-8-4.html)), so it's not available for DBeaver to use to get the function def. Try using the PostgreSQL (Generic) driver when creating a new connection. It has better support for older versions of Postgres.

Comment: I am already using PostgreSQL(Generic) driver and still doesn't work. What if I create pg_get_functiondef(oid) by my own?

Comment: Can't say that I know if that would work for sure, but it's worth a shot. I wouldn't advise it on a production server until you've tested it out on dev. The function is a built-in C function, so I don't think there's an immediate SQL equivalent to use to just drop in to a function definition, but you should be able to use the pg_proc table with select <oid>::regproc to get the proc name from an OID to build something.

Comment: On dev we have new version of PostgreSQL, I think there is no other solution then upgrade database. Thanks for help!